# Access to temps and fan data from within sandbox on OSX?

Tags: xcode, macos, iokit

How can I access SMC information - such as CPU temps and fan speeds, from within an app sandbox (to be app store compliant). I can't see an available API, and yet there are apps on the app store that accomplish this functionality - for instance: https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/monity/id915542151?mt=12

I can get my app to work fine outside of a sandbox (it uses IOKit Framework), but as soon as I put it in the sandbox to make it app store compliant it's dead as there's no available entitlement.

If there's no obvious way to achieve this, is there a means of using some sort of temporary entitlement?

Edit - I can get it to work with the following temporary entitlement:

com.apple.security.temporary-exception.sbpl string (allow iokit-open)

However I do not believe that this would be approved by apple.

Comment: I expect a kernel driver is involved; just guessing though.

Comment: Do you have documentation/tutorial there on his github page and source code of SystemInfoKit? The user has deleted everything

Comment: i have the source code downloaded from GitHub but none of the instructions that were kept on the (very helpful) website.

Answer (score 3):

Running a [quick dump of the Monity widget's symbol table](https://gist.github.com/SamRothCA/a4af1448181a858ce7cb), it would appear to use [this older iStat implementation](https://github.com/Northern-Lights/iStatPro/tree/master/DataMiners), which in turn is mostly based on the IOKitLib userspace API (as opposed to IOKit itself). Does this differ from what you had been attempting? (Care to provide a few more details?)

Comment: I had been attempting to implement this: https://github.com/jBot-42/JSystemInfoKit.  I've also edited my question to note that I can force it to work with a dodgy temp entitlement (although this would not likely be approved by apple)